# Bootstrap modal wont show

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with my modal window not displaying on the screen, I believe the issue is related to the fade css class for bootstrap as when I don't include the class the modal window displays but without the fade class the background appears all in black.

This is my modal window:

```js
function DeleteVenueModal(Name, ID) {
  console.log("delete venue function hit");
  VenueModalID = ID;

  txtVenueModal.innerText = "Delete " + Name;
  $("#VenueModal").modal();
}

DeleteVenueModal("Someone", "34");
```

```css
.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out, -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="modal fade" id="VenueModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 id="txtVenueModal" class="modal-title">Delete </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this venue?</p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" onclick="RemoveVenue();" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" style="float: left">Confirm</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

This is the JavaScript function that opens the modal window:
```

If you to need see any more code just ask

Comment: Can you create a demo or a fiddle?

Comment: Do you call the javascript `$('#VenueModal').modal('show')` ?

Comment: Did you used attributes in your action link on clicking which you are expecting modal?
for example:
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VenueModal">Click me</a>

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the error on JSfiddle but I will keep trying and I have edited the question to include the JS function that opens the modal window

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by downgrading my bootstrap from the latest version available on NuGet to version 3

Answer (score 0):

@Cathal O 'Donnell Check following code. I hope you were expecting the same.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#VenueModal">Click me</a>

<!-- ...................Modal Starts.............. --> 
<div class="modal fade" id="VenueModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 id="txtVenueModal" class="modal-title">Delete </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this venue?</p>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" onclick="RemoveVenue();" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" style="float: left">Confirm</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset your CSS code to:

```
 .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out, -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
       -o-transform: translate(0, -25%);
          transform: translate(0, -25%);
}
.modal
{
  display:block !important;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 1.0 !important ;
}
```

I have modified your class **.modal-backdrop.fade** to **.fade**. If you have parent class .modal-backdrop then you can have it as I couldn't found such class so I removed.

Please try this piece of CSS code and let me know.